# Decoding Aztec barcode

Tags: barcode-scanner, dataformat, aztec-barcode

I scanned an Aztec code and got the following result:

AQEpKCzOLQMf85T0bLRyJEZ3qukry/dsKwebnG2xESMj8JSSgmc=

I would like to know the encoded format and if possible the readable text to see what information is hidden behind the code!

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it the data specified by the person who printed the barcode according to his own rules? Is there any information that the data applies to something in the barcode specification called Aztec? If there is such information, it would be better to analyze it based on it. If it is someone's own unique rule, it will be difficult to get advice and answers without the information of that rule.

Answer (score 2):

Your scanned data is formatted in [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). You can decode it to binary format in almost any programming language or tool like https://www.base64decode.org/

I tried to decode the value but, it isn't readable in any common character sets. You'll have to supply more information on to get any relevant answers. The author of barcode data would be your best bet (what is the usage of the code?)

Comment: This is used by the public transportation department as a throwaway one-way ticket in subways of Tehran. Probably contains a serialized token of some sort.

Comment: How could you see this information?